# открыть fragment из activity

Tags: java, android

Как в приложении Android из страницы `Activity` открыть страницу `Fragment`?

Comment: [Ознакомьтесь](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/95/177345), пожалуйста, с политикой приветствий, лирических отступлений и прочей несущественной информации на этом ресурсе. Так же, Android Studio - всего лишь одна из программ для разработки под Android и к вашему вопросу не имеет непосредственного отношения.

Answer (score 1):

С помощью `Intent`.

#### Из Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, myFragment.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

#### Из Fragment:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), myFragment.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: можно и через FragmentTransaction